# cron job in magento

Tags: magento

I wont to make one minute cron job in magento so i have folow below information 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

so with the help of above  i have made new moduli for this cron  setup this moduli is acitve and displayed in  magento admin panel but cron is not fire

my code for configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Apprika_Cron>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Apprika_Cron>
    </modules>
    <crontab>
          <jobs>
              <Apprika_Cron>
                  <schedule>
                      <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                  </schedule>
                  <run>
                      <model>Cron/Observer::setLifeCycleStatus</model>
                  </run>
              </Apprika_Cron>
          </jobs>
      </crontab>
</config>
```

and the model i have create in  C:\xampp\htdocs\ce\app\code\local\Apprika\Cron\Model\Observer.php

the code for this is

```
class Apprika_Cron_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
         parent::_construct();
        $this->setLifeCycleStatus();
    }
    public function setLifeCycleStatus()
    {

       $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
       $live_concluded=$this->getProductInfoforLifecycle();

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
      if(count($live_concluded)>0){
       foreach($live_concluded as $status=>$value)
       {
           if($status=='live')
           {
               for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++)
               {
                   $productId=$value[$i];
                   if($productId) 
                   {
                        try 
                        {  
                            $product->load($productId);
                            $product->setData('offer_stage','3');
                            $product->save();         
                        }catch(Exception $e)
                        {
                            Mage::printException($e);
                        }

                   }
               }
           }
           if($status=='concluded')
           {
               for($j=0;$j<count($value);$j++)
               {
                   $productId=$value[$j];

                   if($productId) 
                   {
                        try 
                        {  
                            $product->load($productId);
                            $product->setData('offer_stage','4');
                            $product->save();         
                        }catch(Exception $e)
                        {
                            Mage::printException($e);
                        }
                   }

               }
           }
       }
       }


    }
     public function getProductInfoforLifecycle() 
     {  
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $current_date=Date('Y-m-d H:i');  
        $current_date_ts=strtotime($current_date);
        $productarr=array();
        foreach($products as $product)
        { 
            $offer_stage=$product->getOffer_stage();
            $offer_start_date= $product->getOffer_start_date();
            $offer_start_date_ts=strtotime($offer_start_date);
            $offer_end_date= $product->getOffer_end_date();
            $offer_end_date_ts=strtotime($offer_end_date);
            $entity_id=$product->getEntity_id();
            if($offer_stage==2 && $offer_start_date!="" && $offer_end_date!="" && $offer_start_date_ts <=$current_date_ts)
            {
              $productarr['live'][]=$entity_id;
            }if($offer_stage==2 && $offer_start_date!="" && $offer_end_date!="" && $offer_end_date_ts <=$current_date_ts)
            {
              $productarr['concluded'][]=$entity_id;
            }

        }

         return $productarr;
      }  
}
```

but this cron is not call so this records are not update

if i call http://xyz.com/cron.php

then records updated but with the help of cron records not updated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you find the solution ... what is the problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add this line (or a similar line) to your crontab:

```
*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Comment: what would be path for local testing

Comment: It depends on where your Magento folder is located

Comment: what about the localhost/magento/cron.php

Comment: is any another way to call cron rather than manually calling corn.php??

Comment: Yes, just read this article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion i have already read out this link and made run cron successfully